# How to install Linux using ONLY ethernet

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ethernet

How can I install Linux Debian on PC having only Ethernet and no monitor and i/o devices on that PC so after that I can communicate with that PC only through SSH?

**UPD:** also I wanted to do this from Windows, so it's seems that for PXE I gonna use TFTP32 (http://tftpd32.jounin.net)

Comment: Ok I found corresponding software called FAI, will see 

http://fai-project.org

Comment: FAI is a 1GB distro that doesn't not solve your headless needs neither does TFTPD32.

Answer (score 0):

To install debian trought ethernet you need to  set up a TFTP and a DHCP  server which will serve the installation media to machines on your local network. Refer to the chapter **Preparing Files for TFTP Net Booting** from here: [4.5. Preparing Files for TFTP Net Booting](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/install.pdf.en)

Comment: Yeah, I get that for PXE I need this two servers. But most important thing for me is auto-install or installation controlled via SSH.

Comment: this does not even "remotely" answer the question ...